# Making offline version of web apps

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I'm building web apps or website using laravel as php backend and bootstrap for frontend and using mysql (phpmyadmin) database from hosting service. so because in my country internet connection is bad i thinking a way of making my website to be available or can be used without internet connection , so it will be like this

1. When bad or no internet connection my website will load local data like html,js,css and also database mysql from local machine
2. When internet connection is good or available my website will load data like html,js,css and also sync database mysql (phpmyadmin) from local machine into hosting service or otherwise

So how to achieve that?

Comment: Why not building a single Web app and sync only the database once the network server is ready...

Comment: Well because i'm extending my 'normal' website with advance capability like report managing and other things, so i think it will be more better if i can get offline version with sync feature....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Service Worker](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/) to mediate your front-end network connections and store data locally when no connection is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to sync database to remote host, you can use the MySQL replication setup.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

The FAQ has already told you that the connection doesn't need to be always available

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-replication.html

Hope this helps.